# understanding recursion on example

Tags: javascript

I have this example from *freeCodeCamp* :

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

The part I'm not sure I'm getting right, is the line:

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
```

Is that invoking the function `countArray = countup(4)`, which executes after the current one finishes?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code as it executes. Inspect the values and see how it functions. That should answer all/any questions you have about values and when something completes. You can do this in an IDE or even in your browsers debug window.

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger, you can at least add `console.log(n)` as the first line of the `countup()` function. And maybe add `console.log(countArray);` before the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that invoking the function `countArray = countup(4)`

Yes.

> which executes after the current one finishes?

No. Execution of `countup(4)` starts immediately, "stopping" execution of `countup(5)`. `countup(5)` can only resume and push `n` to the `countArray` (and return the array) after `countup(4)` has returned.

Comment: in other words, it would reach it's maximum depth first, and only then the code would resume execution.

Comment: tsamridh86: yes, because up until the condition `n < 1` is met for `n == 0` it will recurse

Comment: so after `countup(0)` all the pushing begins.  `countup(1)` pushes `n=1`, `countup(2)` pushes `n=2`, till `countup(5)`

Comment: @bartc correct.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `countup` happens exactly the same as any other function call. There is no delay or special consideration because it is calling itself.

Consider this "unrolled" version of your example:

```js
function countup_a(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_b(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
function countup_b(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_c(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
function countup_c(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_d(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
function countup_d(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_e(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
function countup_e(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_f(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
function countup_f(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup_g_would_go_here(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup_a(5));
```

Here, none of the functions is calling itself, and there's nothing special about execution order. Before countup_a can complete, it needs the answer from countup_b, which needs the answer from countup_c, and so on... then once countup_f returns a value, countup_e can use that value, and so on... until we get back to countup_a, which gives its result to `console.log`.

The only difference in your example is that, since the functions all have identical code, you don't need lots of them with different names, you just use the same one every time. The calls themselves "stack" in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The moment u call

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
```

another countup is being started parallel to the others running.